# Rails-style Rake Tasks for Sinatra (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sinatra

I can't seem to find a gem or example of anyone using Rails-style rake tasks within a Sinatra app. I would like to clean out my migrations folder and am looking to do something like explained here: [When (if) to consolidate ActiveRecord migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486514/when-if-to-consolidate-activerecord-migrations)

Comment: I found a project with a really nice Rakefile: https://github.com/raecoo/sinatra-template Still wondering if me having to dig so hard is because no one needs those tasks, or if Sinatra just doesn't have the following that something like Rails does.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Rails-style" rake tasks. Rake is not rails-only - you can use it on any project. What tasks specifically do you want to do? You'll probably need to write them on your own, though.

Comment: Well, for me its mainly `rake db:schema:dump` that I am wanting (which I now have). I guess "style" was the wrong word :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why Sinatra Doesn't Do What You Want "Out of the Box"

Sinatra isn't a multi-layer framework in the same way as Ruby on Rails. Specifically, while you can certainly add a database layer to a Sinatra application, it doesn't support ActiveRecord or Rails migrations "out of the box."

If you're looking for standard Rails rake tasks and migration support, why not just use Rails? Sinatra is terrific, but it is not a drop-in replacement for Rails.

#### So You Want Database-Centric Rake Tasks...

If your database connectivity comes from a gem, see if the gem's project has a Rakefile you can re-purpose for your application. For example, the [sinatra-activerecord gem](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord) provides instructions for adding related Rake tasks to your Rakefile.

If you rolled your own database connectivity, then you're probably going to have to roll your own Rake tasks as well. The [documentation for Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is extensive, and the features should allow you to automate the tasks you need.

Comment: I did end up finding some samples and adding some tasks to my Rakefile. ActiveRecord helpers should not be the reason someone chooses Rails over Sinatra, I think we both know that. Thank you for the response!