# adding Name to Devise's User Sign In throws a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, So I'm trying to add a Name entry to my Sign in page using devise and here's what I have so far in view/devise/new.html.erb file.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter     password confirmation" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know you have to extend the attributes that Devise allows do I added this code to my application's controller.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    end
```

I also made sure to add :name to db/migrate/devise_create_users here

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Customization
      t.string :name
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
```

I made sure to rake db:migrate and db:reset, but I'm getting this error and it doesn't make sense to me.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-06 15:07:31 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (235.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 251ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<User:0x007fe82225b928>):
 6:       <%= devise_error_messages! %>
 7:       <div class="form-group">
 8:         <%= f.label :name %>
 9:         <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
10:       </div>
11:       <div class="form-group">
12:         <%= f.label :email %>
  app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:9:in `block in     _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__738282397383517404_70317490899320'
  app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__738282397383517404_70317490899320'


 Rendered /Users/clydiscope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack- 4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (0.9ms)
 Rendered /Users/clydiscope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
 Rendered /Users/clydiscope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (7.3ms)
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Did you edit your migration file after the first time you migrated it??

Comment: No, but I've migrated multiple times after I edited and saved the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue here is you edited one of your migration files and re-ran the migration. Once you create a migration file and run `rake db:migrate`, you cannot edit that file *unless* you rollback to that specific file.

In your case here, you can just create a new migration to add the column `name` to the `users` table.

```
$ rails g migration add_name_to_users
```

Then, edit the file.

```
def up
  add_column :users, :name, :string
end

def down
  remove_column :users, :name
end
```

Now you can run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Does every migration stay in the app forever or can they be consolidated?

Comment: Glad you are now up and running! They can be consolidated, just be very careful. Here is a nice answer on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1490578/2456549